# Moving SSRS Report with parameters to Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, dynamics-crm-2013, bids

Good morning, All.

First let me start off by saying that I'm extremely new at CRM and even after reading umpteen million articles, whitepapers, and blog entries, I still feel completely lost.

I have an instance of Dynamics CRM 2013 On Premise that I'm trying to write custom reports for.  Before I realized that all reports had to be done inside of BIDS, I wrote out a beautiful custom Quote inside of SSRS itself.  I made sure to use the Filtered Views in my query to the database, and the structure of the query seems sound, but I can't seem to upload the .rdl file into CRM.

I get the error:

*Reporting Error*
*Error occurred while setting the data source for the report*

I have two questions:

1. How do I move this report into CRM without having to fully recreate it in BIDS?
2. How do I pass the Quote ID from CRM to this report query?

Thanks in advance for all of your help.

#### *Edit: Added Error Message*

Comment: are you using a shared data source?

Comment: @GuidoPreite No sir.  It's localized to the report itself and connects to the CRM server using Windows Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You *Should* be able to upload the RDL directly to CRM...

Try creating a really basic report with the same data source and something along the lines of "select top 10 from filteredincident" and upload it.

If it works then you know it's something with your query.

CRM is notorious for giving error messages that don't have enough information, or are at worst misleading. I've seen this error when I accidentally used non filtered tables and a autofilter parameter that was incorrect.

Also take a look at the SSRS server that CRM talks to, if it's misconfigured that may cause an issue as well. You may want to try uploading your report to SSRS and run it from there to ensure that SSRS is working correctly.

Comment: Basic reports without filtering or parameters work fine.  Anything more than a simple select and it bombs when I try and upload it.  I've tried everything that I can think of, and all of my reports were created in SSRS first so I know they work there.